# RANK inside the bag?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, rank

Let's say I have set_of_values :

```
a, k
a, l
a, m
b, x
b, y
b, z
```

If I use

```
a = RANK set_of_values;
```

I get:

```
1, a, k
2, a, l
3, a, m
4, b, x
5, b, y
6, b, z
```

What I would like to achieve is RANK, but inside the group.
First :

```
a = group set_of_values by first_value;

(a,{(a,k),(a,l),(a,m)})
(b,{(b,x),(b,y),(b,z)})
```

And what should I do now to get:

```
(a,{(1,a,k),(2,a,l),(3,a,m)})
(b,{(1,b,x),(2,b,y),(3,b,z)})
```

EDIT (added RANK inside foreach)

```
b = foreach a { c = RANK $1; generate c; }
```

I get:

```
2014-03-05 09:55:05,601 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 5, column 20>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'RANK'
Details at logfile: /export/home/pig/pig_1394009645035.log
```

Log file:

```
ERROR 1200: <line 5, column 20>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'RANK'

Failed to parse: <line 5, column 20>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'RANK'
        at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:235)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:177)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.validateQuery(PigServer.java:1571)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1544)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:516)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:988)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:412)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:194)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:170)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:538)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:157)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
```

Comment: Did you try using `RANK` inside a nested foreach?

Comment: I did try, but I'm affraid I'm not good enough in Pig to do it...

Comment: Please post that attempt and then we can see whether it doesn't work or if you've just implemented it wrong. (I don't actually know whether it works or not.)

Comment: grunt> b = foreach a { c = RANK $1; generate c; };

Comment: And what happens? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 1):

This might be too late for a reply, but I found someone posted this on stack overflow only:
[Usage of Apache Pig rank function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22987036/usage-of-apache-pig-rank-function)

P.S: He is using DataFu UDF: Enumerate , and it worked for me.