# macro doesn't work inside foreach?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

My question is related to [RANK inside the bag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151364/rank-inside-the-bag)

I was trying to solve it by macro.
Macro definition and loaded data:

```
DEFINE ranked(A) returns B {
   $B = RANK $A;
};
events = LOAD 'stage.events' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
group_by_msisdn = GROUP events by msisdn;
```

And now tests.
These two work:

```
a = ranked(events);
a = ranked(group_by_msisdn);
```

But when I try to use macro inside the foreach clause I get error.
None of these works:

```
a = foreach group_by_msisdn generate ranked($1);
a = foreach events { b = ranked($1); generate b; }
a = foreach events generate ranked($1);
```

Is it possible to use RANK inside foreach?

Regards

Pawel

Answer (score 0):

Seems not. See [this post](http://ragrawal.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/rank-operator-in-pig-0-11/) in early 2013.

But the author suggest that we can also implement an UDF as a workaround approach in [his another post](http://ragrawal.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/on-writing-python-udf-for-pig-a-perspective/).