# How to get serial number in Pig Script based on column?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

Currently My data is coming in this way but i want my data to show RANK with respect to pid fields changing sequence.My script is this.I have tried rank operator and dense rank operator but still no desired output.

```
trans_c1 = LOAD '/mypath/data_file.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (date,Product_id);  



    (DATE,Product id)
    (2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00XT)
    (2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00XT)
    (2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00XT)
    (2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00XT)
    (2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00OZ)
    (2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00OZ)
    (2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00OZ)
    (2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00VB)
    (2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00VB)
    (2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00VB)
    (2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00VB)
```

The final output should look like this where the rank sequence changes with the change in (Product_id) and resets by 1.Is it possible in pig to do that?

```
    (1,2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00XT)
    (2,2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00XT)
    (3,2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00XT)
    (4,2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00XT)
    (1,2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00OZ)
    (2,2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00OZ)
    (3,2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00OZ)
    (1,2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00VB)
    (2,2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00VB)
    (3,2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00VB)
    (4,2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00VB)
```

Answer (score 1):

This question can be solved by using piggybank functions `Stitch` and `Over`. It can also be solved by using dataFu's `Enumerate` function.

**Script using Piggybank functions:**

```
REGISTER <path to piggybank folder>/piggybank.jar;
DEFINE Stitch org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.Stitch;
DEFINE Over org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.Over('int');
input_data = LOAD 'data_file.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (date:chararray, pid:chararray);
group_data = GROUP input_data BY pid;
rank_grouped_data = FOREACH group_data GENERATE FLATTEN(Stitch(input_data, Over(input_data, 'row_number')));
display_data = FOREACH rank_grouped_data GENERATE stitched::result AS rank_number, stitched::date AS date, stitched::pid AS pid;
DUMP display_data;
```

**Script using dataFu's Enumerate function:**

```
REGISTER <path to pig libraries>/datafu-1.2.0.jar;
DEFINE Enumerate datafu.pig.bags.Enumerate('1');
input_data = LOAD 'data_file.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (date:chararray, pid:chararray);
group_data = GROUP input_data BY pid;
data = FOREACH group_data GENERATE FLATTEN(Enumerate(input_data));
display_data = FOREACH data GENERATE $2, $0, $1;
DUMP display_data;
```

DataFu jar file can be downloaded from Maven repository: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3a%22com.linkedin.datafu%22

**Output:**

```
(1,2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00OZ)
(2,2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00OZ)
(3,2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00OZ)
(1,2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00VB)
(2,2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00VB)
(3,2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00VB)
(4,2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00VB)
(1,2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00XT)
(2,2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00XT)
(3,2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00XT)
(4,2015-01-13T18:00:40.622+05:30,B00XT)
```

**Ref:**
[Implementing row number function in apache pig](https://snehalatastechnotes.wordpress.com/2014/10/18/implementing-row_number-windowing-function-in-apache-pig/)
[Usage of Apache Pig rank function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22987036/usage-of-apache-pig-rank-function)